# Стоит ли использовать шаблоны с большим количеством строгих типов

Tags: c++, function-overloading, шаблоны-с++

Есть функция, реализация которой не отличается при любых типах данных. Но тип данных не может быть абсолютно любым ( всего возможных типов данных которые обработает функция - 9 ).

Вопрос: стоит ли делать шаблон для такой функции, а внутри просто проверять является ли тип данных "правильным", или лучше сделать всё обычной перегрузкой?

Comment: А что это за 9 типов? Чем они отличаются от "неправильных"?

Comment: @Voidificator стандартные типы int, double, bool, char и все модифицированные, которые могут без проблем превратится в std::string. Если же например вставить в фукнцию пользовательский класс, он никак не превратится в строку.

Comment: Рекомендую обратить взор на механизм [явного инстанцирования](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation). Он и дублирования кода позволит избежать, и проблемы с замедлением компиляцией решить (разместит код тех специализаций шаблона, которые Вам нужны, там, где Вам нужно).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще, один из плюсов (не главный, конечно) шаблонов - уменьшение дублирования кода. А так придется писать 9 почти одинаковых (за исключением типов) функций. Дублирование кода! (Или Вы не *ленивый* программист?) Используйте `std::enable_if_t` и отсекайте ненужные типы, для этого этот механизм и был введен в стандарт. Учитывая комментарий про типы, которые преобразуются в `std::string`, можете попробовать использовать `std::is_convertible`. Хотя стоит учесть специфику Вашей задачи, возможно, это недостаточное условие. Вот пример использования `std::is_convertible` с [сайта](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_convertible/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A { };
struct B : A { };

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "is_convertible:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int => float: " << std::is_convertible<int,float>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int = >const int: " << std::is_convertible<int,const int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "A => B: " << std::is_convertible<A,B>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B => A: " << std::is_convertible<B,A>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Про идиому SFINAE можно почитать [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150654/). Варианты использования `std::enable_if` есть [тут](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Если проверка типа при помощи `std::is_convertible` не подходит для данной задачи, то можно сделать проверки типа на основе `std::is_integral`, `std::is_floating_point` и прочих подобных структур. Прочитать про них можно, например, [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral). Полагаю, в задаче может быть обработано более 9 типов, учитывая всякие квалификаторы, типы `int` с размером, разные типы `char` и т.д. В таком случае, использование `std::is_integral` и компании оптимально, поскольку они успешно обрабатывают все подобные ситуации.

Comment: Насчёт `std::enable_if` всё понятно, спасибо. А вот насчёт `std::is_convertible`, оно тут вроде не применимо. Т.к. при выполнении `std::is_convertible<int, std::string>::value`, итог будет `false`.

Comment: @Samilton, а можете приложить к вопросу часть своего кода, какие действия Вы выполняете одинаково для указанных Вами типов, как для std::string?

Comment: @Samilton дело в том, что «числа» и «строки» впринципе разные типы (логически), и то, что мы не ожидаем нормального приведения первого ко второму - нормально. Поэтому мы используем посимвольный перевод, распознаем цифры числа, через ASCII коды строим строку. Как бы число кодируется символами-цифрами, которые мы переводим в символы строки. В данной ситуации Вам стоит сделать во включении явное распознавание такой ситуации, например, через std::is_integral.

Comment: это понятно, просто думал что при проверке на конвертацию std::string будут при этом задействованы std функции. Например для того что бы превращать double, int в string я использую std::to_string(), и она без проблем создает строку из этих типов.

Comment: Насчёт кода, весь тут его изложить будет трудно. Вот ссылка на [репозиторий](https://github.com/Oradle/CppConsoleTable). Собственно идея была в том, что бы добавить функцию addRow в агрументы которой я бы кидал вектор с "правильными" типами данных. И вот код этой функции совершенно одинаковый для любых типов. Т.к. используют уже готовые перегруженные операторы присваивания. Но нельзя допустить что бы там оказался не правильный тип, т.к. тогда нужного перегруженного оператора просто не найдется.

Comment: @Samilton согласен, std::is_convertible больше подходит для иерархий и встроенных типов, в Вашей задаче не смотрится. Тогда используйте std::is_integral и т.п. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral - там внизу страницы приведены еще некоторые подобные проверочные операции.

Comment: Информация из последнего комментария перенесена в ответ.